# Why MongoDB aggregate query return nothing? How I can fix it?

Tags: mongodb

When I run:

```
db.database.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:"$City",count:{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{count:{$gt:10}}}]).pretty()
```

it gives me some results.

However, when I add one condition(Country: "US") at $match part to filter out some unwanted results as the code shown below, it returns nothing.

```
db.database.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:"$City",count:{$sum:1}},
{$match:{$and:[{count:{$gt:10}}, {Country: "US"}]}}]).pretty()
```

How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the doucments in the collection

Comment: I still don't return any result... Should I change something in group? Even for the first query, it doesn't return any response...